# Receiving an echo answer from the controller without the layout

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I have something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index/test",
    data: { from: from, to: to }
}).done(function(res) {
    alert(res);
});
```

and the answer from the controller is:

```
public function testAction()
{
    echo 555;
}
```

But the problem is that, this returns the layout with the answer echo 555;

How can I deny to render the layout and only leave the echo answer?

Answer (score 2):

In actions that you don't want to render any view or layout use these lines of code as appropriate:-

```
//To disable view rendering
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
//To disable layout
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

For example:-

```
public function testAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    echo 555;
}
```

You might wan't to take a look at [contex switching](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch) too, in particular the [ajaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext). This is a more 'ZF' way of doing it and will automatically disable layout and set the correct headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the layout by adding this line of code in your controller action method

`$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();`

```
 public function testAction()
 {
     $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
     echo 555;
 }
```